# How would I stop my AI from patrolling and chasing player then go back to patrol in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

As per title, I've made and modified the patrol AI script from unity and added a chase scripting to it but now when the AI sees the player, it doesn't stop patrolling and continues to patrol but just stares at the player and not chase the player.

The code is as follows:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CHASE : MonoBehaviour 
{

    public Transform player;
    public Transform myTransform;
    static Animator anim;
    public float moveSpeed = 6.0f;
    public Transform[] points;
    private int destPoint = 0;
    private NavMeshAgent agent;

    void Start () 
    {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator> ();
        agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
        agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
        GotoNextPoint();
    }

    void Update () 
    {
        Vector3 direction = player.position - this.transform.position;
        direction.y = 0;
        float angle = Vector3.Angle (direction, this.transform.forward);
        if (Vector3.Distance (player.position, this.transform.position) < 30 && angle < 180) 
        {
            myTransform.position += myTransform.forward * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
            this.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(this.transform.rotation,
                Quaternion.LookRotation (direction), 0.1f * Time.deltaTime * 50.0f) ;

            anim.SetBool ("isIdle", false);
            if (direction.magnitude > 5) 
            {
                this.transform.Translate (0, 0, 0.05f);
                anim.SetBool ("isChasing", true);
                anim.SetBool ("isDeath", false);
            }
            else
            {
                anim.SetBool ("isChasing", false);
                anim.SetBool ("isDeath", false);
            }
        }
        else if(agent.remainingDistance < 0.5f)
        {
            anim.SetBool("isIdle", true);
            anim.SetBool("isChasing", false);
            anim.SetBool("isDeath", false);
            GotoNextPoint();
        }
    }

    void GotoNextPoint() 
    {
        // Returns if no points have been set up
        if (points.Length == 0)
            return;

        // Set the agent to go to the currently selected destination.
        agent.destination = points[destPoint].position;

        // Choose the next point in the array as the destination,
        // cycling to the start if necessary.
        destPoint = (destPoint + 1) % points.Length;
    }
}
```